# Provide options to customize the Snapshot creation and retention period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

How can i provide options to customize the Snapshot creation and retention period for ec2 instances in aws

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [aws ec2 cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/) to manipulate your volume snapshot

For example

```
aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol-1234abcd --description "This is my root volume snapshot."
```

As far as I know, there are no *retention period* for ec2 snapshots, this applies for RDS snapshots.

If you need to apply a retention period on your ec2 snapshots, you would need to manage this yourself, [here a script example](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s261/sh/f1e3e449-f833-425b-b0f7-88c7b4e4d813/cfbd14464344042e1a9f4dffb4193c5f) that would do something like it

Answer (score 0):

There are several scripts that are available online to help you with it, like this one:
https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup

If you have a larger environment that you need to manage and if you need to tackle issues like application-consistent snapshots, different types of recovery options etc… You may want to look for a real backup solution to help you manage it. The company I work for, N2W Software, sells a product call Cloud Protection Manager that provides this functionality and more. If you’re interested, you can see our web site here: www.n2ws.com